# How to update a task dynamically in the syncfusion's gantt (only one task)

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, gantt-chart, ej2-syncfusion

In the gantt's documentation, i didn't find a method to update a single task data. All we have for updating is the updateDataSource() method and the worst is that we need call refresh() after it to see the update in the dom which refresh all the tasks and not the only modified task.
In this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc-qx53eg) i've tried only pass the task i need to update to updateDataSource() but the result is that only that same task will be displayed 
In [the gantt's editing demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/gantt/editing) when a task is updated via the dialog, only that task will refresh and not all task , there should be a method that is not exposed in the api that does it

i'm using gantt's react lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can update a particular task using **updateRecordById** method. For this we need to inject **Edit** module. Please refer the below documentation link.
**Documentation** - https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/gantt/managing-tasks/#update-task-values-using-method

```
var ganttObj = document.getElementById('Default').ej2_instances[0];
var data = { TaskID: 2, Duration: 7 };
ganttObj.updateRecordByID(data);
```

Sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc-hynwz7?file=index.js